# grab a argument as regex pattern inside a shell script

Tags: regex, shell

This is simple script to run ls with filter :

```
sh myscript.sh ".pyc"
```

myscript.sh :

```
echo "---------------------------"
for i in `ls | grep '.*\.pyc'`; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

it will do 'ls' and only show *.pyc. Now i want to put that pattern in the argument :

```
sh myscript.sh ".pyc"
```

and modify the script :

```
echo "---------------------------"
for i in `ls | grep '.*\$1'`; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

But this doesn't work. it returns empty result. How to properly insert that **$1** in the regex while inside the shell script ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace everything with this: `printf '%s\n' *"$1"`.

Or alternatively just run one of `printf '%s\n' *.pyc`, `ls *.pyc`, `ls -d *.pyc`, etc.

You probably want `*.pyc` (a shell glob/wildcard which expands to all files ending `.pyc`), as opposed to using grep.

Comment: I can't replace the loop (for loop) , because later i will insert some additional code in the loop.

Comment: @andio `for i in *"$1"; do echo "$i"; done`